# Using Adobe fonts on my bachelor's thesis?

Tags: fonts, minionpro, truetype, licensing

My idea is to use Myriad Pro as the sans serif (bold) font for the titles and Minion Pro for the main text.

But now I see that these are licensed fonts and I'm not free to use them. Obviously i'm not making any money at all, it's just my bachelor's thesis, but I don't want trouble with this.

I am forced now to replace Myriad Pro with:
A) Google's PTSans (will do fine, but it's not the same)
C) Vegur (free font, but doesn't have italic)

And Minion Pro will be replaced with
A) Adobe's source serif pro. (It's from Adobe)
B) Google's Crimson Pro (better? has pro in the name so it must be)

Please share your thoughts

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. Are you looking for the best free replacements for Myriad Pro and Minion Pro? That seems highly opinion based.

Comment: Specifically for Myriad Pro Bold you might want to check [Adobe Fonts](https://fonts.adobe.com/). If you create an Adobe account, there is a (very limited) collection of free fonts available through Adobe Fonts. Last time I checked Myriad Pro Bold was one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer the question, which fonts to use for your thesis. If you won't publish it, nobody will ever care if you used the Adobe fonts.

However, you had a reason to choose these fonts. If you share that reason here, we might be able to come up with some ideas.

There is a font catalogue for LaTeX: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/

Crimson Pro is a new fork of the Crimson font, the fork has been redesigned by a professionell designer.

To get an impression, why don't you skip through the newest manuals? The list for the announcements is here: https://lists.dante.de/pipermail/ctan-ann/

Move into September and e.g. have a look at the scontents manual (if your TeX-installation is up to date, you get it with `texdoc scontents` on the command line). There are a lot of packages with a beautifully typeset manual.